# How to model path-based data

Tags: hash, redis, set

I need to model data in redis where the keys are file paths, and each path has N key/values with it.

I am currently modeling the data using Hashes.

```
HSET /products/clothes/pants/501-jeans "title" "Levi 501 Jeans"
```

This works fine, however I want to be able to get a list of all "pants" hashes "children". I can do this via

```
KEYS /products/clothes/pants/*
```

However [redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands/keys) states `KEYS pattern` should not be used in production.

I was thinking of creating a SET of all "paths" associated with hashes, but im still not sure how/if I can search over those.

Thoughts on how to best model this type of data?

Comment: Relatively new to redis, but I think using a set to store all of the keys "underneath" /products/clothes/pants is a good one. Not sure what your search criteria is but you'll easily be able to get a list of all of those hash keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i've modeled the data and it seems to work fairly well.

```
resources::/path/foo => Redis Hash of Resource data
resources::/path/foo/bar => Redis Hash of Resource data
resources::/path/foo/cat => Redis Hash of Resource data
resources::/path/foo/cat/dog => Redis Hash of Resource data

children::/path/foo => Redis Map [ /path/foo/bar, /path/foo/cat/, /path/foo/dog ]
children::/path/foo/bar => Redis Map [ /path/foo/bar, /path/foo/cat ]
children::/path/foo/bar/cat => Redis Map [ /path/foo/dog ]
```

I have to manage the **children:: maps** any time i add/remove a **resources:: key**

I chose modeling **children::** using Redis **maps** so its impossible to have duplicate path keys, however using a list may work as well (easy to